# compilation error in boost serialization, undefined reference

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have included these header files.

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
```

and then I have two lines:

```
ofstream s_dict("save_dict.archive");
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa_dict(s_dict);
```

while compiling:

```
g++ -lboost_serialization -lboost_system coord.cpp
```

it throws a long list of errors out of which the first error is:

/tmp/ccRMDC8f.o: In function `boost::archive::text_oarchive::text_oarchive(std::ostream&, unsigned int)':
coord.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive13text_oarchiveC2ERSoj[_ZN5boost7archive13text_oarchiveC5ERSoj]+0x25): undefined reference to`boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl::text_oarchive_impl(std::ostream&, unsigned int)'

It is getting undefined reference to boost functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reordering `g++ coord.cpp -lboost_serialization -lboost_system`